# Como alterar um campo de busca para um ícone, para mobile e tablet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

> Gostaria de criar um menu semelhante à este abaixo, porém, nos dispositivos de resolução menor que 800px, não estou conseguindo mudar o campo de busca, para o ícone da lupa.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="divLogo input-group" style="float: right;">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <!--Como alterar este input para um icone? -->
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">BUSCAR</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```